# How to read column and rows with Python and iterate through the entries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, for-loop

I have a CSV file with the host addresses in the column, and the ports for them in the rows, I would like to go through the columns and then scan for the corresponding ports in the row.

I've come up with this code, this works if I manually use the cell with host IP and port.

```
import socket
import csv

lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
 
line_number = 0

while line_number  < len(lst):
    line_number  = int(line_number +1)
    
with open('temp.csv', 'rt') as f:
    mycsv = csv.reader(f)
    mycsv = list(mycsv)
    h = mycsv[line_number][0] 
    line_number  = int(line_number +1)
while line_number  < len(lst): 
    line_number  = int(line_number +1)
with open('temp.csv', 'rt') as f:
    mycsv = csv.reader(f)
    mycsv = list(mycsv)
    p = mycsv[line_number][2] 


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = h
port = int(p)

def portScanner(port):
    if s.connect_ex((host, port)):
        print("Closed")
    else:
        print("Open")

portScanner(port)
```

Sample CSV

```
ip,port 
1.1.1.1,80,443,22
2.2.2.2,80,21,22
3.3.3.3,111,22,21
.
.
.
.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First skip over you header using `next()`. Then you can read each row by first taking the `ip` address and then reading all other entries as `ports` using Python's `*` operator. For example:

For example:

```
import csv
import socket

def portScanner(ip, port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    
    if s.connect_ex((ip, port)):
        print(f"  Port {port}: Closed")
    else:
        print(f"  Port {port}: Open")


with open('temp.csv') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = next(csv_input)
    
    for ip, *ports in csv_input:
        print(f"IP: {ip}")
    
        for port in ports:
            portScanner(ip, int(port))
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, and sorry for being not clear here, I am new to python. I am now getting an error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.1.1.1' I looked online and all recommended to make it float, but it didn't help as well. I also tried to import the ipaddress module with no success. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: I have updated the solution now I can see what the actual format of your CSV file is